# safari does not allowed cross-domain cookies in iframe

Tags: p3p

IE & Safari Browser blocks cross-domain cookies in an iframe.

e.g.
I have two websites, let's say they're `example.com` and `anotherexample.net`.

On `example.com`, I have one page `http://example.com/someform.asp` and in this page i am using cookies. When I open `http://example.com/someform.asp` directly in browser, it is working fine.

On `anotherexample.net`, I have page `http://anotherexample.net/page.asp`, this page contains an `IFRAME SRC="http://example.com/someform.asp"`. Now when we open `http://anotherexample.net/page.asp` page in browser, the cookies for `example.com` are not saved. In Firefox and chrome this problem doesn't appear.

I found that using p3p policy we can fix this, but after setting below p3p policy in IIS response header and its works for IE only.

```
P3P : CP="This is  a P3P policy! See  http://www.workplaceanswers.com/privacy-and-terms/"
```

But, I am still getting the same error in safari. I have tried with different p3p policy values as below but not able to fix it.

```
P3P : CP="CUR ADM DEV HIS TEL STA STP COM”
P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT”
P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA”
```

Is there any way to make this work in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution posted by **Vitaliy Ryepnoy** at github: https://github.com/vitr/safari-cookie-in-iframe

The gist:
In the main window (`example.com`), you should detect if the browser is safari,if so, you redirect the user to `iframe.com/fix_safari.html`, where you set a cookie and redirect again to `example.com`.

Then, safari let's you set a cookie in the iframe, because there is already a cookie there from `iframe.com`

worked for me, after hours of frustration

more details and code example in the github page

Comment: I'm having trouble with this currently, and it does not look like this works any more unfortunately. Do you know of a solution that could help for newer versions of Safari? My specific use case is hosting a Next.js app that is placed on partner websites inside of an iframe, and we use Auth0 to authenticate users. Auth0's cookies are causing the issue.

Comment: I didn't touch this area for a long time, so not sure what is the current state of safari and iframes cookies

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was suffered from cross domain cookie issue in safari web browser in mac & iPhone devices. 
                  So, I was create one temp file on client machine and save all cookies in that temp file for One domain. And when I  was try to read that cookies from another domain file then in that file i was made changes like if cookies are not set then fetch cookies data from that temp file And again set cookies for that second domain. It's work successfully.